# Esiste il termine dileggiatorio?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Discutendo con un collega, è stata pronunciata la frase:

> Ha un comportamento dileggiatorio

Ho cercato sul web ed sul sito della Treccani ho trovato i termini

- Dileggiare (verbo)
- Dileggiatore (colui che dileggia)

Mentre ho trovato su [Wiktonary versione inglese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dileggiatorio) il termine `dileggiatorio`

Sinceramente, nella versione inglese di Wiktionary non nutro molta fiducia, quindi vorrei sapere se come termine è corretto o se in luogo dello stesso, dovrei usare il termine `dileggiatore`

Quindi con la frase che diverrebbe:

> Ha un comportamento dileggiatore

Comment: "Dileggiatore" sembra un sostantivo (chi dileggia), mentre invece "dileggiatorio" è un aggettivo e mi sembra più corretto, anche se in effetti non credo sia molto usato. Comunque è corretto (vedi anche ad es "provocatorio" http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/provocatorio/).

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Certo, ero arrivato a questa deduzione ma sembra strano il fatto che non trovi il termine su Treccani.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Che cosa intendi per “corretto”? Che è formato in modo coerente con altri vocaboli analoghi o che è attestato da qualche parte?

Comment: @DaG esatto, intendo è formato in modo coerente con altri vocaboli analoghi.

Comment: Ricercando su Google Libri se ne trovano parecchie occorrenze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dileggiatorio** è un aggettivo derivato appunto dal verbo dileggiare e significa *"che genera/produce dileggio"* .

Grazie [a questo utile documento](http://wwwdata.unibg.it/dati/corsi/24169/60754-Lista_morfemi_italiano_Facchi.pdf) scopro che si parla in questo caso di *morfema aggettivatore*, in cui il suffisso *-atori-* trasforma il verbo in aggettivo.

> **-atori-:** suffisso aggettivatore con valore di “generante N”.
>
> liberare → liberatorio
>
> denigrare → denigratorio
>
> diffamare → diffamatorio
>
> infiammare → infiammatorio

Per esperienza personale, non mi pare sia molto usato, ma è corretto.